# Jasmine tohaveBeenCalledWith() Object comparison

Tags: javascript, jasmine

My jasmine test is currently failing for me on `expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(myArray)` with the following message that I'm not sure how to interpret:

> Expected spy mySpy to have been called with [ Object({ type: Function,
> name: 'foo', **value: [[ Object({type: Function, name: 'one' value:
> '1' }), Object({type: Function, name: 'two', value: '2'}), ... ]]** })
> ]
>
> but actual calls were [ Object({ type: Function, name: 'foo', **value:
> [[ Object, Object, ... ]]** }) ]

Note that the expected object had full typing and values for the `value` property, but on the actual call, Jasmine only picked up that they were Objects, with no details on the inner values for them. I understand that jasmine has a difficult time comparing functions and you need to pass in the same reference to both, which I am, but why is Jasmine not giving the full detail on the actual calls, and why is it failing just because they are objects?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, I deal with that issue like so:

```
// get a handle on the arguments that the most recent call the spy was invoked with
const arguments = mySpy.calls.mostRecent().args;
console.log({ arguments });
expect(arguments[0]).toBe(....); // assert the first argument to be of ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to function as a workaround for my tests and the `.toEqual()` check seems to work just fine for the argument. Still not sure why `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` fails differently though